# Apache Nifi: Replacing values in a column using Update Record Processor

Tags: csv, replace, apache-nifi

I have a csv, which looks like this:

```
name,code,age
Himsara,9877,12
John,9437721,16
Razor,232,45
```

I have to replace the column `code` according to some regular expressions. My logic is shown in a Scala code below.

```
if(str.trim.length == 9 && str.startsWith("369")){"PROB"}
else if(str.trim.length < 8){"SHORT"}
else if(str.trim.startsWith("94")){"LOCAL"}
else{"INT"}
```

I used a `UpdateRecord` Processor to replace the data in the `code` column. I added a property called `/code` which contains the value.

`${field.value:replaceFirst('^[0-9]{1,8}$','SHORT'):replaceFirst('[94]\w+','OFF_NET')}`

This **works** when replacing code's with

1. length less than 8 with "SHORT"
2. starting with 94 with "LOCAL"

> I am unable to find a way to replace data in the column, `code` when it's equal to 8 digits **AND** when it starts with 0. Also how can I replace the data **if it doesn't fall into any condition** mentioned above. (Situation which the data should be replaced with `INT`)

Hope you can suggest a workflow or value to be added to the property in Update record to make the above two replacements happen.

Comment: INT cannot has starting 0. It should be a string.

Comment: @Lamanus changes made. Thx for pointing out. My real data set doesn't contain mistakes like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `length` and `startsWith` functions.

```
${field.value:length():lt(8):ifElse(
  'SHORT', ${field.value:startsWith(94):ifElse(
  'LOCAL', ${field.value:length():equals(9):and(${field.value:startsWith(369)}):ifElse(
  'PROB', 'INT'
)})})}
```

I have put the line breaks for easy to recognize the functions but it should be removed.

By the way, the INT means that some string values to replace? Sorry for the confusion.

---

Well, if you want to regular expression only, you can try the below code.

```
${field.value
  :replaceFirst('[0-9]{1,8}', 'SHORT')
  :replaceFirst('[94]\w+', 'OFF_NET')
  :replaceFirst('369[0-9]{6}', 'PROB')
  :replace(${field.value}, 'INT')
}
```

Comment: How can I insert a regex into that? I mean instead of using a function..

Comment: You haven't mentioned how I can deal with the AND scenario using regex.

Comment: `0[0-9]{7}` is this not enough?

Comment: length must be equal to 9 and start with 369. It must satisfy both conditions to be replaced with `PROB`

Comment: Your question statement was `I am unable to find a way to replace data in the column, code when it's equal to 8 digits AND when it starts with 0` this makes me so confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203144/discussion-between-himsara-gallege-and-lamanus).

Comment: Btw, I have modified my answer depends on your codes, not the statements. Check out.