# Replacing text values doesnt work as expected in Apache-NiFi

Tags: regex, replace, apache-nifi

My csv file :

```
id,name,package
1,sachith,16434646
2,nalaka,12347834
3,john,6574654
4,albert,834758
```

`UpdateRecord` processor should change this into :

```
id,name,package
1,sachith,0434646
2,nalaka,0347834
3,john,old_pack
4,albert,old_pack
```

I used following `replaceFirst` operation as custom property. `/package`

`${field.value:replaceFirst('(^12)','0')
:replaceFirst('(^16)','0')
:replace(${field.value},'old_pack')`

Here I used `replace(${field.value())` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047663/apache-nifi-replacing-values-in-a-column-using-update-record-processor).

But my output is having :

```
id,name,package
1,sachith,0old_pack
2,nalaka,0old_pack
3,john,old_pack
4,albert,old_pack
```

Replacement Value Strategy : Literal Value

`Record Reader : CSV`

`Schema Access Strategy : Use String Fields from Headers`