# Replace column values using Apache NiFi

Tags: replace, apache-nifi, nifi-processor

I have a sample csv looks like this

```
ID,FNAME,PROBLEM_COL
1,sachith,
2,nalaka,
3,john,
4,adams,
```

Always `PROBLEM_COL` value is empty. I want to replace empty with `null` string.

For that I used `UpdateRecord` processor and `CSVReader` with `Use String Fields From Headers`
Custom value as `/PROBLEM_COL` and `${field.value:replaceFirst('','null')}`

This runs without error/warning. But `PROBLEM_COL` is not replaced. I had referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047663/apache-nifi-replacing-values-in-a-column-using-update-record-processor), but this does not solve my issue. My headers are in block-letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replaceEmpty('null')` instead of replaceFirst

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#replaceempty

Answer (score 1):

try to change your regex to be something like

```
',$'
```

which means: comma followed by end of line

Answer (score 1):

With processor `UpdateRecord` you can use

```
replace( /PROBLEM_COL, '', 'null' )
```